# Check co-ordinates validity - UITextField - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, uitextfield, coordinates

I have an iOS app with two `UITextFields` which allow the user to manually enter latitude and longitude co-ordinates. One thing I am puzzled about is, how can I make sure the entered data is a valid coordinate?

- Coordinates much be numbers only
- Coordinates can have a minus sign.
- Coordinates cannot have spaces in them.

Would you say there are any other checks I should do?

And how can I check if the `UITextField.text` have letters as well as numbers? Could I use Regex?

**Update**

So to clarify my question these are the types of strings I am trying to check:

- -2.42353463466 (Valid)
- 32.131ertf22 (Not valid - it contains characters)
- 1.23141 4124 (Not valid - it contains spaces)

Comment: How to you separate longitude and latitude, or x/y ?

Comment: @Larme: There are 2 text fields, I guess

Comment: @Larme Yes latitude and longitude are entered by the user in two separate ```UITextFields```.

Comment: Do you allow "," or "." ? According maybe to localized separator? Like "-3.44" ?

Comment: @Larme Oh right well in that case I allow ".".

Comment: you can check my edited answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Regex to validate the number, but an easier way of doing it is probably to just try and convert each text field's string value to a `double` using `NSNumberFormatter` and see if it worked:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:myTextField.text];

if (number != nil) {
    // The number is correct!
    double coordinate = number.doubleValue;
    NSLog(@"Coordinate: %f", coordinate);
} else {
    // The number is incorrect!
    NSLog(@"Invalid coordinate entered.");
}
```

Once you've got both `double`s for each coordinate part, you can then form a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` using the `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` function.

After forming your `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, you can use the `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid` function to check that the latitude and longitude parts are in the correct ranges.

Comment: Would ```number``` return nil if the text string was something like "2.12331uvchs212"? Because obviously a coordinate does not have letters?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Yes, your three examples you edited in to your question all give the results you want with this method (an `NSNumber`, `nil`, `nil`).

Answer (score 1):

you can check if particular CLLocationCoordinate2D is valid or not

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(myCoordinate)) {
  NSLog(@"Coordinate valid");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Coordinate invalid");
}
```

Comment: welocome sir @Supertecnoboff

Comment: You answer is good but does not cover everything I need and also I had already ticked another answer, so I can't change it anymore.